# Como trabalhar com o UnaryOperator<T> do Java?

Tags: java, interface, programação-funcional

Seguindo o texto da doc
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

> `UnaryOperator<T>`
> Represents an operation on a single operand that produces a result of the same type as its operand.

Isso quer dizer que eu estou produzindo um novo objeto e não alterando aquele sobre o qual eu apliquei a operação unária ? Que possibilidades essa interface me dá, e quando devo usá-la ?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não. Isto quer dizer apenas que o resultado produzido é do mesmo **tipo** do valor usado como operando.

Se vai retornar um objeto completamente novo ou se vai retornar o próprio operando só depende de você e do design das suas classes.

Por exemplo, a classe `LocalDate` é imutável e seus métodos criam novas instâncias ao invés de alterar o estado interno do objeto. Digamos que vc tenha uma lista de `LocalDate` e queira criar uma nova lista com as datas acrescidas de 10 dias:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    UnaryOperator<LocalDate> operator = localDate -> localDate.plusDays(10);

    List<LocalDate> localDates = Arrays.asList(
        LocalDate.of(2022, 04, 01),
        LocalDate.of(2022, 04, 02),
        LocalDate.of(2022, 04, 03));

    List<LocalDate> localDatesIn10Days = localDates.stream()
        .map(operator)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(localDates); // [2022-04-01, 2022-04-02, 2022-04-03]
    System.out.println(localDatesIn10Days); // [2022-04-11, 2022-04-12, 2022-04-13]
  }
}
```

Vc vai terminar com 2 listas diferentes cada uma contendo instâncias diferentes de `LocalDate`.

Mas se vc estiver trabalhando com `Date`, que é mutável, nada te impede de alterar e retornar o próprio operando.

```java
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    UnaryOperator<Date> operator = date -> {
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 10));
      return date;
    };

    List<Date> dates = Arrays.asList(
        Date.from(Instant.parse("2022-04-01T00:00:00.00Z")),
        Date.from(Instant.parse("2022-04-02T00:00:00.00Z")),
        Date.from(Instant.parse("2022-04-03T00:00:00.00Z")));

    List<Date> datesIn10Days = dates.stream()
        .map(operator)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(dates); // [Sun Apr 10 21:00:00 BRT 2022, Mon Apr 11 21:00:00 BRT 2022, Tue Apr 12 21:00:00 BRT 2022]
    System.out.println(datesIn10Days); // [Sun Apr 10 21:00:00 BRT 2022, Mon Apr 11 21:00:00 BRT 2022, Tue Apr 12 21:00:00 BRT 2022]
  }
}
```

Neste caso vc vai terminar com 2 listas diferentes, mas com objetos iguais.